# VB.NET Windows Service issues

Tags: vb.net, windows-services, vb.net-2010

I have a service that runs and saves a file to a remote server.  This works within the service but now I need to send a command

```
Public Declare Function cwbDQ_Create Lib "Cwbdq" (ByVal qName As String, ByVal lName As String, ByVal sName As String, ByVal queueAttr As Integer, ByVal errorHandle As Integer) As Integer

Public Declare Function cwbDQ_SetConvert Lib "Cwbdq" (ByVal dataHandle As Integer, ByVal convert As Integer) As Integer

rc = cwbDQ_Create(queueName, libName, sysName, attrHandle, errHandle)
rc1 = cwbDQ_SetConvert(dataHandle, convert)
```

This is where is stops processing, the service keeps running it just doesnt do anything with this.